# Why can't I add \n after a float in C to create another line?

Tags: c

```
printf("%f  %.3f  %.2f  %.1f", 4.5678, 4.5678, 4.5678, 4.5678);
```

I tried putting \n at the end of the series of floats to separate the line

```
printf("%f  %.3f  %.2f  %.1f", 4.5678, 4.5678, 4.5678, 4.5678)\n;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That \n should be inside the strings of printf not after it

```
printf("%f  %.3f  %.2f  %.1f \n", 4.5678, 4.5678, 4.5678, 4.5678);
```